# Kitkat Behaviour: SMS Broadcast Receiver not working after fresh installation and if app is not launched

Tags: sms, android-broadcast

I have an Android app that listens to SMS messages. This is in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSListner" >
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The broadcast receivers works fine if the app is installed and opened(For all android versions).

- In case, below kitkat version, if app is install and is not open, still it receives the SMS in OnRecieve method
- In case of KitKat, it is not working till the time application is launched once.

When I send a SMS, non Kitkat device(GB version) receives the sms but Kitkat version doesnot.

OnRecieve code is:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
{

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.v( "KK TEST APP", "===============SMS Received===============" );
    if ( action.equals( ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED ) )
    {
        Log.v( "KK TEST APP", "action.equals( ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED )" );
    }
    else
    {
        Log.v( "KK TEST APP", "other message" );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps will not receive broadcasts until they have been launched the first time. This is Android security. They used to be able to, but Google has changed this behavior somewhat recently.

Comment: Thanks David! I appreciate your feedback on my concern. This mean that we would need to launch the application once for broadcast to work. Well any workaround can be done to achieve the prior functionality?

Comment: Yes you would. The only exception to this is applications that are pre-installed as system applications. Here is Google's note: 

"Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications."

Comment: Mine case is Q:If My application has no activities and it just has a receiver(here SMS receiver), How can I activate and receive common broadcast intents?
Answer I got was:
A:Actually your above application is actually Not Stopped State when it’s first installed. Becuase It has no launcher clickable chance. It can receive normal broadcast smoothly If you do not manually force-stop it.
- See more at: http://androidyue.github.io/blog/2014/01/04/package-stop-state-since-android-3-dot-1/#sthash.c7IWoPpe.dpuf  <br/> As per answer it should work automatically, but its not working in Kitkat

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service to call a broadcast receiver. Also, in onCreate method in main activity call this service and this should remain active although your app is killed. Regrads

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Creating a new service  and starting it in Oncreate will require launching the application. My sole purpose after installation of app is not to launch the application even once and still the receivers should work.